# How to tell which type annotations support __iter__

Tags: python, iterator, abstract-syntax-tree, mypy, python-typing

If I parse the ast of a Python file and see that a variable has a type annotation, e.g. `Mapping`, how can I tell if that annotation supports `__iter__`?

One option would be to look through https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html , make a list of everything which supports `__iter__` (e.g. `Iterable`, `Iterator`, `Collection`, ...), and check if a given variable's annotation is in that list.

But, this feels brittle - is there a better way? I need to be able to do this just by parsing a variable's annotation from its ast - running `iter` on a variable isn't an option.

Comment: A type can support `__iter__` without having a type annotation that specifies that. `Mapping`, for example, doesn't *imply* iteration, but it doesn't preclude it, either. Why do you need to rely on annotations?

Comment: Because this is for a static analysis tool

Comment: The best you can probably do is check if the hint is a subclass of `collections.abc.Iterable`, which should be true as long as it is one of the other standard types in `collectors.abc`, but may not be true of someone's custom protocol.

Comment: (And actually, `Mapping` *does* imply iteration, as it's a subclass of `Collection`, which is a subclass of `Iterable`. Sorry, my mistake.)

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that but `isinstance(typing.Iterable, collections.abc.Iterable)` returns `False`

Comment: Because it's not an *instance* of `Iterable`. `isinstance(int, int)` returns False as well. Use `issubclass()` instead. (`typing.Iterable` is just an alias of sorts for `collections.abc.Iterable, via some sort of wrapper.)

Comment: you need some way of parsing class used for annotation (including all of members inherited from its' parents) and look if it has `__iter__` magic method I guess

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to resolve the FQN of the given annotation, and then retrieve the stub for the module it belongs to (e.g `typing.pyi` from typeshed) and then recursively decypher all the methods that class implements and check whether it implements the protocols you want it to do. Obviously this is a complicated procedure, so if you want to make stuff easier instead of parsing and partially evaluating module stubs, you can try to import to module dynamically and then do a simple `issubclass` check.